# Bootstrap Progress bar doesn't work with Panel Inside

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a panel inside a progress bar but when I add the panel the progress bar does not work/increase width.

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels

Here is what I tried:

http://jsfiddle.net/fS2zq/

> ```
>     <div class="progress progress-striped active" style="height:100px;border-style:solid;">
>     <div class="panel panel-primary" style="width:15%;height:100px;">
>         <div class="panel-heading">
>              <h3 class="panel-title" style="text-align:center;">Division 10</h3>
>
>         </div> <strong><div align="center">0 PTS</div></strong>
>
>     </div>
>     <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width: 50%"></div>
> </div>
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you wont somethig like this http://jsfiddle.net/fS2zq/1/

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" style="width:15%;height:100px;float:left">
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it my self, the problem was the positioning of

```
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width: 50%"></div>

<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width: 50%">
 <div class="progress progress-striped active" style="height:100px;border-style:solid;">
    <div class="panel panel-primary" style="width:15%;height:100px;">
        <div class="panel-heading">
             <h3 class="panel-title" style="text-align:center;">Division 10</h3>

        </div> <strong><div align="center">0 PTS</div></strong>

    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```